# "It was always" vs "I was always" vs "I would always"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

> No matter where I went with her, **it was always the right place.**
>
> No matter where I went with her, **I was always in the right place.**
>
> No matter where I went with her, **I would always be in the right place.**

Is any of the examples ungrammatical? Or they just emphasize different things? If so, how?

Comment: The second and third mean almost exactly the same thing. The first has a different meaning, in which the fact of being in the right place is not related to the person called 'I'.

Comment: The third doesn't sound right to me, but I'm not sure it's a grammatical problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one talks about the place, the second about you and the third one is more like a habitual thing that happened many times.